# referencing a vector::front works, but vector::begin doesn't

Tags: c++, stdvector, segmentation-fault

I have this bit of code:

```
cerr << client->inventory.getMisc().front()->getName() << endl;
vector<itemPtr>::iterator it;
it = client->inventory.getMisc().begin();
cerr << (*it)->getName() << endl;
```

Let me explain that a bit:

`client` is a `tr1::shared_ptr` that points to an object that has a member named `inventory` that has a private `vector<itemPtr>` member accessible by `getMisc()`. `itemPtr` is a typedef for `tr1::shared_ptr<Item>`, and `getName()` returns a private `std::string` member of `Item`.

Essentially, `client->inventory.getMisc()` boils down to a `std::vector`, and I'm trying to get an iterator to its first element.

The problem is that the fourth line segfaults.  Apparently either the iterator or the shared_ptr it points to is invalid.  I used the first cerr statement to test if the vector itself was valid, and it prints as it should, so I think it is.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Alternatively, what would you guys do to debug this?

Comment: Rahter than "explain a bit" can you provide code. The people on this site are rather good at understanding code and working out what it means. And it is lot more precise than an English description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exactly what is the signature of `getMisc`?

If you're actually returning a `std::vector<itemPtr>` then you are returning a *copy* of the list.  In that case, the first access pattern will work (slowly) because the temporary copy doesn't get destroyed until after `front` finishes executing, by which time the `itemPtr` itself is copied into a temporary.  The second fails because after getting at the iterator with `begin`, the temporary falls out of scope and is destroyed, leaving the just-created iterator hanging.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a nice bit of psychic debugging.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it returns.  What should I do instead, return a reference?

Comment: Fixed the problem.  I put the vector manipulation in a member function of `inventory`, which I probably should've done to begin with.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks all.  @Max: You can return a (possibly const) reference, or even store the vector itself internally in a shared_ptr and return that, but keeping the vector private works great.

Answer (score 1):

> what would you guys do to debug this?

Step though the code to see what's different about what `front()` returns and what `(*it)` returns.

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't inspect the variables well with gdb.  When I try `p client->inventory.getMisc().front()`, gdb says 'There is no member or method named inventory'.  When I try `p *it`, I see it holds a `shared_ptr<Item>`.  When I try `p **it`, gdb says 'One of the arguments you tried to pass to operator* could not be converted to what the function wants'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the vector isn't empty? It's possible that `front` and `begin` behave slightly differently and `front` could work by pure chance, while additional checks in the iterator itself cause the seg fault when it's used.